# Bootstrap error validation error color (red) not showing

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to validate a form using Bootstrap. So far I managed to validate the form but my form is supposed to change the color into red when an error is made. But red color is not shown.

Where did I make a mistake?

```html
<form #loginForm="ngForm">
  <div class="form-group" [class.has-error]="userName.invalid && userName.touched" [class.has-success]="userName.valid">
    <label for="userName" class="control-label">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userName"
      [(ngModel)]="loginObject.userName" id="userName" #userName="ngModel" required>
    <span class="help-block" *ngIf="userName.invalid && userName.touched">
      <p>Name is required</p>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" [class.has-error]="password.invalid && password.touched" [class.has-success]="password.valid">
    <label for="password" class="control-label">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" 
      [(ngModel)]="loginObject.password" id="password" #password="ngModel" required>
    <span class="help-block" *ngIf="password.invalid && password.touched">
      <p>Password is required</p>
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you include bootstrap.css ?

Comment: yes i included if i not import forms also not showing

Comment: everything works except error validations colors

Comment: have you checked in your dom showing red color?

Comment: and the second solution is that you can add color using style tag in your HTML.

Comment: that's what my question not showing red color when errors made

Comment: Did you add a css file?

Comment: in css file add this code .help-block { color:red;}

Comment: yes i added bootstrap.css in angular.json

Comment: why should i add .help-block { color:red;}? bootstrap will give us error messages as red

Comment: if it's not working so we can add alternate solution for this issue

Comment: what is issue ?and  my all earlier projects its working fine

Comment: maybe your css is override by other css file

Comment: right click and check inspect element

Comment: no its not overide by other

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189309/discussion-between-shubham-chhapre-and-abhiram).

Answer (score 0):

```
<form #loginForm="ngForm"> <div class="form-group" [class.has-error]="userName.invalid && userName.touched" [class.has-success]="userName.valid"> <label for="userName" class="control-label">Username</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userName" [(ngModel)]="loginObject.userName" id="userName" #userName="ngModel" required> <span class="help-block" style="color:red" *ngIf="userName.invalid && userName.touched"> <p>Name is required</p> </span> </div> <div class="form-group" [class.has-error]="password.invalid && password.touched" [class.has-success]="password.valid"> <label for="password" class="control-label">Password</label> <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" [(ngModel)]="loginObject.password" id="password" #password="ngModel" required> <span class="help-block" style="color:red" *ngIf="password.invalid && password.touched"> <p>Password is required</p> </span> </div> </form>
```